# Wordpress custom image sizes upcsacle image

Tags: php, wordpress

I have build a custom wordpress website and added few custom image sizes.

The problem is when user uploads smaller image (700x300).
Than image doesn't crop to fit custom aspect ratio.

How can I upscale images to fit my crop size (1:1 aspect ratio)?

Here is my crop function:

```
add_image_size( 'article-crop', 700, 700, true );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be fixed by adding this code to your theme’s functions.php file. It upscales images to fit all thumbnail sizes and crops them correctly.

```
/*  Thumbnail upscale
/* ------------------------------------ */ 
function alx_thumbnail_upscale( $default, $orig_w, $orig_h, $new_w, $new_h, $crop ){
    if ( !$crop ) return null; // let the wordpress default function handle this

    $aspect_ratio = $orig_w / $orig_h;
    $size_ratio = max($new_w / $orig_w, $new_h / $orig_h);

    $crop_w = round($new_w / $size_ratio);
    $crop_h = round($new_h / $size_ratio);

    $s_x = floor( ($orig_w - $crop_w) / 2 );
    $s_y = floor( ($orig_h - $crop_h) / 2 );

    return array( 0, 0, (int) $s_x, (int) $s_y, (int) $new_w, (int) $new_h, (int) $crop_w, (int) $crop_h );
}
add_filter( 'image_resize_dimensions', 'alx_thumbnail_upscale', 10, 6 );
```

[Source](https://alx.media/code/2013/10/thumbnail-upscale-correct-crop-in-wordpress/)

Comment: Add this `if ($aspect_ratio > 1) { if ($orig_w < $new_w) return null; if ($orig_h < $new_w) return false; } elseif ($aspect_ratio < 1) { if ($orig_h < $new_h) return null; if ($orig_w < $new_h) return false; } else { return null; }` after `$size_ratio = ...` if you don't want to upscale images, but to stop wordpress from creating images with wrong ratios.